# replace with line on the left in vscode diff

Tags: visual-studio-code

if we do a diff in vscode as follows, is there a way to replace the right portion on the screen with text on the left

Here's the vscode screen
[image]

Here's what I hope it can achieve (see the arrow there)

[image]

Comment: you can copy paste the text from the left pane to the right pane, the right pane is just an editor with all capabilities

Comment: no nice recommendations for extensions?